# Display a report in custom object

Tags: visualforce, lightning, reporting

I need to display a report in a custom object. I'd also like to filter the report depending on the object name. I found a code and tried a few things with it but I am not getting any result : the Visualforce section is just blank.

Here is my code :

`<apex:page standardController="Project__c">
<apex:iframe src="https://neofi.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/00O57000007EbDFEA0/view?run=now&parameter_Name={!Project___c.Name}" scrolling="true" frameborder="0" />
</apex:page>`

I'm also not sure where to find the parameter for this report...

Thanks